# Using Bulk Insert in PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

```
declare 
    cursor c_emp is select * from employees;
    type t_emp is table of employee%rowtype;
    r_remp t_emp;
    count number;
begin 
    for i in c_emp loop
    begin 
        select count(*) into count from employees where department_id=i.department_id;

        if count is null then
            insert into sometable values (x,y,z)
        else
            insert into sometable values (a,b,c)
    end loop;
end;
```

There are around a million records to be inserted. How can I use bulk collect and improve the code to insert records in less time?

Comment: Please read the following article about collections and bulk processing in Oracle. If you still cannot do what you need update your question with what exactly is the problem (with the code indented and without syntax errors): [Bulk Processing with BULK COLLECT and FORALL](https://blogs.oracle.com/oraclemagazine/bulk-processing-with-bulk-collect-and-forall)

Comment: Looping over a result set is probably the worst thing you can do, performance-wise. Your employees table has a million rows in it? That must be a big company.

Comment: @eaolson do you have any other option to do the same?

Answer (score 1):

Huh, you're looping million times (i.e. as many times as there are rows in the `employees` table). I'm not sure that was your intention; perhaps you meant to loop through **distinct departments**, instead? Can't tell for sure as you didn't explain what lies behind that piece of code.

Besides, `count` won't return `null`; it'll return 0 if there are no employees in a certain department:

```
SQL> select count(*) from emp where deptno = -1;

  COUNT(*)
----------
         0
```

so your code wouldn't work properly anyway.

---

An example based on Scott's sample schema (as I don't have your tables). I'm going to insert a department number and "option" (whether employees exist or not) for each department. Note that I used `exists` which doesn't have to count all rows that match the criteria; at least one is enough to quit searching, which should perform way better.

In my sample tables, nobody works in departments 10 and 40:

```
SQL> select d.deptno, e.ename
  2  from dept d left join emp e on e.deptno = d.deptno
  3  order by d.deptno;

    DEPTNO ENAME
---------- ----------
        10
        20 SMITH
        20 ADAMS
        20 JONES
        20 SCOTT
        30 JAMES
        30 TURNER
        30 MARTIN
        30 WARD
        30 ALLEN
        30 BLAKE
        40

12 rows selected.
```

Here's the code; no need for PL/SQL but - if it must be used, just enclose the following `insert` statements into begin-end block (or create a stored procedure out of it).

```
SQL> create table sometable (deptno number, employees_exist varchar2(1));

Table created.

SQL> insert into sometable (deptno, employees_exist)
  2    select distinct d.deptno, 'Y'
  3    from dept d
  4    where exists (select null from emp e
  5                  where e.deptno = d.deptno
  6                 );

2 rows created.

SQL> insert into sometable (deptno, employees_exist)
  2    select d.deptno, 'N'
  3    from dept d
  4    where not exists (select null from emp e
  5                      where e.deptno = d.deptno);

2 rows created.

SQL> select * from sometable order by employees_exist, deptno;

    DEPTNO EMPLOYEES_EXIST
---------- ---------------
        10 N
        40 N
        20 Y
        30 Y

SQL>
```

No looping, no slow row-by-row processing.

The final solution might depend on what you're really inserting into `sometable`; dummy column names with no explanation don't help a lot.